# Copy Final Layout to Shared Layout without overwriting languages | Sitecore 9.3

Tags: c#, content-management-system, sitecore

I am pretty new to Sitecore. My predecessor created all english pages in the Experience Editor and didn't have the knowledge about Shared and Final Layouts, so all the Renderings are in the Final Layout and all Shared Layouts are empty. Now, another language was added and the content manager overseas edited the content in the Sitecore Content Editor and was told that all translations will be shown in the Frontend Layout. But as you will already know, the pages are blank except header, navigation and footer, that were set up as shared by our IT.

I found out that you can copy/paste the Raw XML values from the Final to the Shared Layout, but this overwrites/deletes the content in the other language and activates the fallback (in this case our english content).

Worst case is to re-edit all the content in the second language or re-create the Renderings in the Experience Editor, but that would be a pain in the butt. Is there a solution to adapt the Final Layout structure from one language and use it as a Shared Layout or as a Final Layout for another language? We are using Sitecore 9.3

Big Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in such specific case you can move the content from the Final Layout field to the Shared Layout field, but there are quite a few cases to keep in mind when doing so. This is far from a complete list, and some of it depends on how your solution is implemented, but here are at least a few things to consider and keep in mind:

"Fallback" works a bit different in the Layout fields compared to the other Sitecore fields, as the page layout is computed using Layout Deltas. Basically you may have a set of renderings in the `__Standard Values` item, that can then be "modified" with a layout delta on the item Shared Layout and then modified again in the Final Layout. So in your scenario you probably want to make sure you *move* the raw XML rather than *copy* it from Final to Shared Layout.

If there are multiple languages/versions of the item, you'll have to consider the content of all versions and have the Final layout cleared on all of them. There's a shortcut for this. Just verify the content first to avoid unwanted side effects. If there are intended local changes on some languages or versions, those should be re-written as new layout deltas so they align with the new content in the shared field. That's sometimes easier said than done, but it sounds like this wouldn't be the case in your scenario.

There are a few built-in API methods to evaluate the content of the renderings (computing all the layout deltas basically). It may be a good idea to make a SPE script or similar, to make a copy of all the computed renderings before changing things and then re-run that after the migration to verify that end result is still the same. This is obvious more relevant on larger more complex setups.

It's usually a good idea to review the `__Standard Values` items and check that renderings are only in the Shared Layouts field. (There are perhaps valid cases where it would make sense to have content in the standard values final layout field, but I'd see those as edge cases)

Though not directly connected to Layout evaluation, I've seen many solutions with mistakes regarding the evaluation of the datasource on renderings in multi-language scenarios. Most implementations have some logic in place for checking the existence if the datasource item and applies some kind of fallback when the datasource item is absent, such as hiding the component or do some other fallback. However, if the page is on two (or more) languages, and a component (in the Shared Layout for example) is only translated to one of the languages, the datasource item will exist for both languages but the fields will be null*. So simple datasource checking logic may not work as intended, like components being rendered with blank content instead of collapsing etc. (* With language fallback enabled, the behavior may be different depending on the scenario and how it's configured.)